# Railstutotal (Michael Hartl): Error with Listing 6.25

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I followed the Rails Tutorial so far and it's all been working fine until I get to Listing 6.25. The tutorial says that "rails test" should be green here but I am getting red.

Error

Failure:
UserTest#test_email_addresses_should_be_unique [location]
expected to be nil or false

I'm 99% sure that I followed the book exactly and can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :name, :email

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, 
        format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, 
        uniqueness: true
end
```

and user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                       foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

end
```

Comment: If the book says to use attr_accessor :name, :email in the user model it must be an old edition (prior to Rails 4 so prior to mid 2013). If that's the case you should get the latest version which is for Rails 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of the book you have but this is the way it is now in the book:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

There is no attr_accessor :name, :email

You should also change uniqueness to:

```
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Or else the same email can be used just by using capital letters or downcasing. I think that way it should work fine. 
Here is the link to the newer book, in case you are not using it which is better because you will run into less errors:

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#sec-uniqueness_validation

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line, it messes up ActiveRecord

```
attr_accessor :name, :email
```